# Slight issue with QFTing two qubits

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, quantum-fourier-transform

Let's consider two qubits and the corresponding computational basis $\{|0\rangle\, |1\rangle, |2\rangle, |3\rangle\}$. In binary form, any of these vectors can also be written as a product $|x_1\rangle\otimes |x_2\rangle$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ can be either $0$ or $1$.

Let's take these two qubits and perform the following operation on them:

\begin{align*}|y\rangle&=(H\otimes \mathbb I)(CR_2)(\mathbb I\otimes H)|x_1x_2\rangle\\ &=\frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle+e^{2\pi ix_2/2^2}e^{2\pi ix_1/2}|1\rangle)\otimes(|0\rangle+e^{2\pi ix_2/2}|1\rangle)
\end{align*}

where $H$ is the Hadamard gate and $R_2$ is the $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix $[1, e^{2\pi i/2^k}]$.

Looking at that first exponential, if $x=|x_1x_2|_2$ in binary, then in decimal notation $x=2x_1+x_2$, which means that $$|y\rangle=\frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i x/2^2}|1\rangle)\otimes (|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i x_2/2}|1\rangle)\tag 1$$
which is to be compared to the QFT of $|x\rangle$ in the product representation:

$$|\tilde x\rangle=\frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i x/2}|1\rangle)\otimes (|0\rangle+e^{2\pi ix/2^2}|1\rangle).\tag 2$$

These two are supposed to be the same thing, with qubits in reversed order. However, something seems remiss to me: the second factor in $|y\rangle$ has $x_2$ in the exponential, while the first factor of $|\tilde x\rangle$ has $x$. This means they are not equal after all.

Is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Should it be $|y\rangle=\frac{1}{2}(|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i x_1/2^2}|1\rangle)\otimes (|0\rangle+e^{2\pi i x_2/2}|1\rangle)$?  I think, as you hinted, you just had an endianness convention issue.  The qubits *are* in the reverse order, aren't they?

Comment: @MarkS Well, yeah, I'm just comparing that $e^{2\pi i x_2/2}$ in $|y\rangle$ with the $e^{2\pi i x/2}$ in $|\tilde x\rangle$. Since $x\ne x_2$, doesn't that difference mean that $|y\rangle\ne |\tilde x\rangle$?

Comment: $x$ is two qubits (or one qudit, with $d=4$), while $x_2$ is a single qubit, right?

Comment: I just made a change to equation 1 - let me know if that's correct?

Comment: @MarkS Sorry for the late reply. You are correct, $|x\rangle$ is indeed the tensor product $|x_1\rangle|x_2\rangle$. So for example if $x=3$ then $|3\rangle$ can be written in binary as $|11\rangle$ so that $x_1=x_2=1$.

Comment: @MarkS As for the change you have made: I think it is not correct, as $$e^{2\pi ix_2/2^2}e^{2\pi ix_1/2}=e^{2\pi i(2x_1+x_2)/2^2}=e^{2\pi i x/2^2}$$ using the relation $x=2x_1+x_2$.